# Regex matching the following Input in SQL Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Column with the following values

```
ReportID
--------
19
19,20,21
20,19,21
20,21,19
119,21
1191,21
```

I need to match the the rows which have 19 as a value (i.e. reject last two rows)

Is there a better way to do this than the query used below ? (Using combined regex)

My Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [StoreBI_Validation].[dbo].[PortalNotifications]
WHERE ReportID like '%,19,%' 
   or ReportID like '19' 
   or ReportID like '19,%' 
   or ReportID like '%,19'
```

Comment: The correct solution is to **not** store comma separated values in a column. If you properly normalize your data you wouldn't have that problem. A quick workaround is to store a leading and trailing comma, e.g. `,20,19,21,` then you using `%,19,%` is enough

Comment: If you normalize your data, not only would you not have this problem, but your queries would work significantly faster as you could use an index on the reportID column. There's no way of using an index with your current query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test
WHERE ','+ReportID+',' like '%,19,%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddcce/5)

Or this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT reportid
FROM (
    SELECT A.ReportID
        ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data
    FROM (
        SELECT ReportID
            ,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(ReportID, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM Test
        ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) B
WHERE Data = '19';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [StoreBI_Validation].[dbo].[PortalNotifications]
WHERE CHARINDEX(',19,',ReportID)>0
```